# Makefile: target that depend on a whole folder

Tags: makefile

I'd like to turn a bunch of images into a video (video `video1.mp4` is made from the files `video1/*.mjpg`), using a Makefile. I tried:

```
SOURCES=video1.mp4 video2.mp4
all: $(SOURCES)

%.mp4: $(shell find % -type f)
        ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i '$*/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p $@
```

but it does not work, the `%` is not turned into the `video1`-like prefix. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Indeed, `%` is not expanded inside `$(shell ...)`. Why are you using `find` anyway? Wouldn't `$(wildcard */*.jpg)` do exactly what you want?

Comment: @tripleee I heard that find was more compatible than wildcard in another SE question. But as I understand, your wildcard will look in all folders, not the one specified by the destination.

Comment: So does `find`, in spades; it will traverse all subdirectories as well. If you only want to look in a specific folder, obviously do that instead.

Comment: @tripleee Well, I was hoping that `find % -type f` would be expanded into, e.g. `find video1/ -type f` (so it would not loop over all directories) , but the problem is that it does not.

Comment: That's still wrong if you don't want to traverse subdirectories. You can restrict the reach of `find` with `-maxdepth` but simply matching a wildcard is simpler and more efficient. `$(wildcard video1/*.jpg)` then?

Comment: Oh, I don't care about traversing subdirectories as I don't have nested subdirectory anyway. But I don't want my files `video1.mp4` to be recreated if a file changes in `video2/`. And I want my makefile to be generic, I don't to write one rule per file, like `video1.mp4: $(wildcard video1/*.jpg)`, `video2.mp4: $(wildcard video2/*.jpg)`, `video3.mp4: $(wildcard video3/*.jpg)`... I want a single rule, like `%.mp4: $(wildcard %/*.jpg)`, except that this surely don't work. But the answer proposed by AProgrammer works nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the dependencies in another way as `%` is indeed not handled as you would like. Something like this (replacing the cat by an adequate ffmpeg call) should do the trick:

```
DESTS=video1.mp4 video2.mp4
all: $(DESTS)

define add_dependencies
$(1): $(wildcard $(1:.mp4=)/*.jpg)
endef

$(foreach dst,$(DESTS),$(eval $(call add_dependencies,$(dst))))

%.mp4:
    cat $^ > $@
```

Note:

1. I'm using the built-in wildcard instead of find. The way I'm using it, I don't recurse in sub-directories, but your call to ffmpeg hints to me that wasn't desired.
2. I'd suggest if possible using `$^` instead of doing the file matching a second time in ffmpeg.
3. This is for GNU make, but I don't think other makes accept the `$(shell)` syntax if they aren't targeting a wide GNU make compatibility.

Comment: Who, that's quite a complicated syntax ^^ (eval + call) But it seems to work fairly well, thanks a lot! Concerning your point 2, I'm not sure if ffmpeg allows this kind of syntax, and I'm afraid to have poorly ordered pictures with the GNU wildcard (but `$*/*.jpg` seems to work fairly well)

Comment: Eval+call is a very common pattern when generating makefile fragments as here. In order to improve the interface, I often encapsulate it in another call, but here that would make it more obscure.

Comment: @tobiasBora BTW, if you want to control the order, GNU make has a sort function (which removes the duplicates, which is often handy, but at times confusing)